# Cpp Friend function has no access to private static members

Tags: c++

I have a class with a private static variable. The main function should change the value in the variable, but even if I set the main function as a friend of the class the compiler tells me that the variable is private and not accessible from main.

Example:

ClassA.h:

```
namespace nameA{    

class ClassA {
    private:
        static int varA;

    public:
        ClassA(){};

    friend int main(void);
};
}
```

ClassA.cpp:

```
namespace nameA{

int ClassA::varA = 0;

}
```

main:

```
int main(void){
    ClassA::varA = 42; //ERROR
}
```

I don't know if "friend" also allows access to static members or if I have to find another solution.

Comment: The function main is not declared in a namespace except the global namespace.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It because friend function `main` in ClassA is located in `nameA` namespace.

If you want to declare as friend the `int main(void)` function, that located in global scope,  you should do it this way:

```
friend int ::main(void);
```

Whole source (compiled in VS2015):

```
int main(void);

namespace nameA {

    class ClassA {
    private:
        static int varA;

    public:
        ClassA() {};

        friend int ::main(void);
    };
}

namespace nameA {
    int ClassA::varA = 0;
}

int main(void) {
    nameA::ClassA::varA = 42;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `friend` declarations grants friendship to a function named `main` in the namespace `nameA`, not the global `main` function.

Your code is equivalent to

```
namespace nameA
{
   int main(void);

   class classA
   {
      ...
      friend int main(void);
   };
}
```

You need to declare `main` before the namespace starts.

```
int main(void);

namespace nameA
{    
   class classA
   {
      ...
      friend int main(void);
   };
}
```

should work